# Example connector property file to provide standalone Kafka Connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am starting to play with **CDC and Kafka connect**

After countless hours trying, I have come to understand the logic

1. Set Kafka Connect properties (bin/connect-standalone.sh) with your cluster information
2. Set Kafka Connect configuration file (config/connect-standalone.properties)
3. Download your Kafka connector (in this case MySQL from Debizium)
4. Configure connector properties in whatevername.properties

In order to run a worker with Kafka Connector, you need to

```
./bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties
```

which answers:

```
INFO Usage: ConnectStandalone worker.properties connector1.properties [connector2.properties ...] (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:62)
```

I know we need to run:

```
./bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties myconfig.properties
```

My issue is that I cannot find any format description, or example of that myconfig.properties field.

**【Extra Info】**
Debizium configuration properties list:

1. https://docs.confluent.io/debezium-connect-mysql-source/current/mysql_source_connector_config.html#mysql-source-connector-config
2. https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.5/connectors/mysql.html

**【Question】**
**Where can I find an example of the connector properties?**

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use connect-distributed if you only want to use one config to start the worker and all the examples you do find use json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, but here is an example of properties for this connector :

```
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector
connector.name=someuniquename
database.hostname=192.168.99.100
database.port=3306
database.user=debezium-user 
database.password=debezium-user-pw
database.server.id=184054
database.server.name=fullfillment
database.include.list=inventory
database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers=kafka:9092 
database.history.kafka.topic=dbhistory.fullfillment
include.schema.changes=true
```

The original config is the one from the documentation which I converted from json to properties : https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.5/connectors/mysql.html#mysql-example-configuration

Comment: Correct, I found that too, but I am not sure of: 1. Does it need to be JSON or that format. After trying with connector, it complains: contains no connector type. I have the connector, and the path and so on.

Comment: @David Standalone mode takes Java `.properties` files, not JSON like Distributed mode. Any error about connector classes not found are indeed an issue with your `plugin.path`

Comment: @Lucas, I have learnt that, if you are using stand alone, you need to use .txt file with your format. If you are using a Kafka cluster, then you will need the JSON file.